# Proof that 0 in last pivot position of matrix via gaussian elimination means there are infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I'm having trouble understanding why a 0 in the last pivot position after applying gaussian elimination to eliminate all the variables but 1 means that there are infinite solutions to the set of equations.

I've tried examples and it's all worked out but I'm curious about a proof for this.

Comment: Counterexamples: A system of equations with corresponding row-reduced augmented matrix $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$ in fact has *no* solutions despite the final row.  Further, the system corresponding to $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$ has exactly one solution despite the final row.

Comment: Once the question is clarified how you intend, you are essentially going to be asking for proof of a specific part of the [invertible matrix theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html).  There are going to be *many* routes you can take, for example showing that the kernel of the original matrix is nontrivial.  Suppose that $x'$ is a solution to $Ax=b$ and $o\in\ker(A)$ such that $o\neq 0$.  Then you have $A(x'+\lambda o) = b$ for all values of $\lambda$.  Assuming you are working in an infinite field, that implies infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Is there anything special then if there is a 0 in the last pivot location?
How can your first example be possible because isn't the second row saying 0=1?
Also does your second example have one solution despite the 3rd row because of the amount of degrees of freedom?

Comment: Assuming that there is no pivot in the final column (*which would have implied the system was inconsistent*) **and** there is at least one other column without a pivot, then there will be infinitely many solutions.  This condition is commonly misidentified as "*having a row of all zeroes,*" usually as a result of focusing too heavily on examples with the same number of equations as unknowns.

Comment: "*How can your first example be possible because isn't the second row saying $0=1$?*"  Exactly, the second row is interpreted as $0=1$ which is an impossibility, implying that there are no solutions to the system.  That could have happened for the system $\begin{cases}x+y+z=1\\2x+y+z=1\\3x+2y+2z=3\end{cases}$ for example, which yields a similar example to the first augmented matrix given in my first comment after row reduction (*but for this case, the first row would have been $[1~1~1~|~0]$ instead*).

Comment: I don't know what ker means yet so I will have to learn more to understand what you said in your second comment but as for your third comment about having at least one other column without a pivot, doesn't this example counter that?
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    3 & 8 & 1 \\
    0 & 4 & -4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
which becomes
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 4 & -4 \\
    0 & 2 & -2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: "having at least one other column without a pivot *in the fully row-reduced echelon form of the matrix*"  Your example in your most recent comment is not in row-echelon form.  The kernel of a matrix, denoted $\ker(A)$, is the set of all vectors $v$ such that $Av=0$.

Comment: sorry I meant that it becomes:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 2 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I think I understand your proof now but I'm not sure if its what I'm asking - perhaps I am asking my question too soon.